# Rails sending gzip or uncompressed file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gzip

As per rails guides, compression is on atuomatically for assets unless specifically defined differently `config.assets.gzip`.  These, and the uncompressed files are being generated on the application's shared/assets folder.

*Context: nginx server version 1.14 + Phusion Passegner 6.0 running*

How can I tell whether the call to the server is invoking the `.gz` vs `uncompressed` asset (assuming the client browser is not using the cached version)?

Answer (score 2):

In the client request, there will be the [`Accept-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header

It may contain smth like `gzip, deflate, br`

In this case, gzipped resource will be sent if there's one available. In the response headers there will be `Content-Encoding: gzip` then